# Can I set a custom address for reminders in El Capitan?

Tags: macos, reminders

I want to get a notification to buy something at store I only rarely go by. "Reminders" doesn't seem to know the store name but I can find the address on Google Maps no problem. But I can't seem to enter that address in the El Capitan "Reminders" app.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just start typing.
It will search Contacts, recent locations, even what appears to be a Bing/Google search for matching locations.
Click it in the list once you've narrowed it down far enough.

[image]

Comment: Thanks :)  What if Bing/Google can't match the business name for some reason, is there a way to just enter the address? (I can't get that to work and just rephrased the original question to specify that).

Comment: @rassom Try adding a contact for the company in your address book (with the correct address) and see if you can type in the name of the company then.

Comment: @Lizzan I can, but it's a bit cumbersome for everytime I want a reminder somewhere that it doesn't recognize as a business.

Comment: @rassom True, it's more of a solution for few places and more repeated visits.